# Sequelize: does not allow update in sequelize fields?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I work a short time with Sequelize, but there is a need that a field x should not allow changes.

I would like to know if there is any property / functionality that does not let a particular field get update.

Comment: Can you please give example or elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can create a hook `beforeUpdate`.[link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html)